# Create jpeg image from php/html

Tags: php, output, jpeg

I have an html table that uses php to populate it with some simple values and changes the background colour based on given variables.
I want to be able to generate/create/output a jpeg image from the table using a button.

Simple example...

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="image.php" method="POST">
//table html & php code here//
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Print table" />
</form>
</body>
<html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You want a button to generate a copy of the table? Is that it?

Comment: yes - to output the file to a jpeg

Comment: I'm very much afraid that the surest way to do this is to rebuild the image using gd primitives and ttftext. Otherwise you need a HTML interpreter, running as an independent executable. This is what PhantomJS does.

Answer (score 0):

http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html

I hope/guess this can help you.

Comment: Thanks...not sure it's what I'm looking? Does it capture the whole screen or just the image?

Comment: you select elements by id

Comment: But this requires a server-side executable that loads the same page the user is viewing, in the context of that user; or am I missing something?